# Multiple Child Kernels running in Parallel in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

```
    _global__ ChildKernel1(void* data){
        //Operate on data
    }


_global__ ChildKernel2(void* data){
        //Operate on data
    }


_global__ ChildKernel3(void* data){
        //Operate on data
    }

__global__ ParentKernel(void *data){
        ChildKernel1<<<16, 2>>>(data);
        ChildKernel2<<<64, 3>>>(data);
        ChildKernel3<<<32, 4>>>(data);
        ChildKernel4<<<16, 5>>>(data);

    }
    // In Host Code
    ParentKernel<<<256, 64>>(data);
```

I want to run all the child kernels in parallel. So what do I do?

Comment: Down vote should accompany the reason also.

Comment: I didnt downvote. What is the problem ? It would be helpful if you can post a small reproducer and describe whats the problem. I am assuming you know that dynamic parallelism needs CC3.5 GPU.

Comment: The basic reason for a downvote is given by hovering your mouse over the downvote button.  "This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear..." Does your question show evidence of having researched the topic to discover possible answers?  In addition, the comment above states "What is the problem?" That could be an indicator of an unclear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [dynamic parallelism section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism) of the programming guide?

As you've shown it, each thread in your `ParentKernel` will execute the code consisting of the 4 calls to child kernels.  This complicates the answer.

So, with respect to the individual threads, yes, the various kernels may run in parallel, between threads.

But remember that cuda kernels issued by a given thread into the same stream will be serialized.  Therefore, with respect to each individual thread in `ParentKernel`, the individual child kernels launched from that thread will be serialized.

To get the kernels in a single thread to have the possibility to run in parallel, launch them into separate [streams](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#unique_401424053).

Finally, the big caveat:  Just like [asynchronous concurrent execution of kernels](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#conurrent-kernel-execution) launched from the host, device side kernels may only run "in parallel" as resources permit.  There is no guarantee of parallel execution of kernels.